# Embed a output path in logic path in shopify

Tags: shopify

I basically want to retrieve the gateway user has used while checkout and on that I have to apply logic path.

I have tried

```
{% if {{ gateway }}=="Cash on Delivery (COD)" %}
<tr>
<td><strong>Shipping Taxes</strong></td>
<td>Rs. 19</td>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Liquid rendering in checkout that you can set. You can add scripting to the Thank You page where you would be able script with Liquid. The change for you would be to access the order itself. Try

```
{% if order.gateway == 'Cash on Delivery (COD)" %}
   ... your special code here
{% endif %}
```

You'll see that that works.

Answer (score 0):

David's right, you're limited to where you can add liquid in the checkout (Thank You page only). If that's where you're putting your code, it should work if you just remove `{{ }}` from around the `gateway` variable.

[This page in the Shopify doco](http://docs.shopify.com/support/settings/checkout-and-payment/how-do-i-customize-my-thank-you-page#additional) gives an example:

```
{% if gateway == 'Cash on Delivery (COD)' %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```